Can one do an issur derabanan so that his friend can do a mitzva doraisa
There’s a rule not to do an aveira to benefit another but would it apply in a scenario where the purpose of performing an issur derabanan is to enable another person to perform a mitzva doraisa.

Welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks for bringing your questions here! Could you please [edit] this post to flesh out the question body? The body should independently and clearly present the question. It would be helpful to include more information about what you already understand, e.g. the rule that you assert. Also, please apply our jargon policy as well as you can.

This relates to an extensive discussion in halacha regarding how we rule on the principles of "אין אומרים לאדם חטא בשביל שיזכה חברך" (Shabbos 4a) versus "רבי סבר ניחא ליה לחבר דלעביד הוא איסורא קלילא ולא ליעבד עם הארץ איסורא רבה" ('Eruvin 32b), as well as the parameters and application of those principles. See more discussion here.

What do you mean by "enable"? Can you give an example?
